# How to define in Swift a generic structure that points to another structure with the same type?

Tags: ios, swift, swift5

I'd like to have a simple generic structure that looks like this:

```swift
struct Node<T> {
    let id: String
    let data: T

    let previousNode: Node<T>?
}
```

Unfortunately this produces the following error: [image]

I tried to implement a protocol with associated type, but this doesn't help as well.
[image]

Do you know what's the easiest way to write a generic `struct` that points to the object with the same type?

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/using-indirect-modifier-for-struct-properties/37600/2

Comment: In practice, it turns out using a struct for this kind of data structure isn't really useful anyway. Nodes are fundamentally references, not values. If two things share a previousNode that should be the *same* node. That's what a reference type means, which means you should use a class here. (This was a very common mistake in the early days of Swift when we all ran out and tried to build Haskell-style data structures with structs and enums, and it took us a long time to realize this wasn't just very difficult, it wasn't even correct. Haskell values are reference types. They're just immutable.)